# Parameter '@s' must be defined

Tags: c#, mysql, database, procedure

I'm having problems to run a script inside a custom action. The script creates and sets up a database in a localhost MySQL server.

Concretely, I have problems with one of my procedures:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdateAutoInc`(IN `increment` BIGINT) 
BEGIN
SET @s = concat('ALTER TABLE tblactionservices AUTO_INCREMENT ',increment);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
SET @s = concat('ALTER TABLE tblbannedclient AUTO_INCREMENT ',increment);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

In the script, before this procedure, I have 2 other procedures that run perfectly.

The error I get when I install the application is "Parameter '@s' must be defined". Looking for the Internet I found this [blog](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2009/05/mysqldatamysqlclientmysqlexception-parameter-id-must-be-defined.html) but I added the "Allow User Variables=True;" with no luck. With this piece of text, the script crashes directly on the first procedure. Indeed, it crashes always, no matter what it finds (procedures, tables...). The error I get is absolutely useless "You have an error in your SQL Syntax; check the manual bla bla", so I can't find the problem.

This is the class I'm using to run the script from c#:

```
private void ExecuteSql(string DatabaseName, string Sql)
        {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection { ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;User Id=root" };
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Sql, connection);

        command.Connection.Close();
        command.Connection.Open();

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        finally
        {
            // Closing the connection should be done in a Finally block
            command.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

The script wasn't manually typed but it was automatically generated from PhPMyAdmin. The version of MySQL server is 5.5 and the connector version is 6.5.5.0

Comment: In your last 2 procedures have you use parameters or not...

Comment: if u r passing parameter then u have to firstly get it from your ExecuteSql function like this 
private void ExecuteSql(string DatabaseName, string Sql,string param ){/////////////Code///////}..try this

Comment: No, I don't use parameters in the other two. This is one of them: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `PopulateDefaultTables`()
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO tblbodytype(bodytype) values ('Delgado');
 INSERT INTO tblbodytype(bodytype) values ('Normal');
END$$

Comment: your procedure is ok but your function from which you are calling that procedure doesn't contain any data for @s,,that's why it creates problem....are you using Mysql or sql server..

Comment: I didn't understand very well what you meant with the param. Yes, the procedure has a param, but I'm not calling the procedure but creating it, so what param should I pass and how? I'm using MySQL.